# Sets of Ordered Pairs

Tags: functions

I read from a source that ‘a function is a set of ordered pairs’, although it did not specify whether there has to be a common mathematical relationship between the x and y-values of each ordered pair.

So, if we cannot write a rule for a particular set of ordered pairs, can we still consider it to be a function?

Comment: So you are asking if the premise "Every function is a set of ordered pairs" is false, meaning we have to find a counterexample?

Comment: Yes.  A function is not the same thing as a formula.  However, there is a rule that no two of the ordered pairs have the same first element.

Comment: Functions were originally defined (see [history of the function concept](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Functions.html)) as giving a "rule" for values, until Fourier showed that trigonometric series can sum to even very "unruly" functions. Dirichlet then proposed the modern definition based on arbitrary assignment of values to arguments, which was later formalized into sets of ordered pairs, where two different elements with the same first component do not occur. So no, under modern definition you do not need any rule

Comment: @Conifold That should be an answer, not a comment.